# Handling errors with Javascript and Node.js (then/catch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, try-catch

Let's assume I have this pseudocode inside a routes.js file:

```
var pkg = require('random-package');

app.post('/aroute', function(req, res) {
    pkg.impl_func(data, function (err, result) {
        myFunction(entity).then(user=>{
            //DO_STUFF_HERE
            res.render('page.ejs');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.render('error.ejs');
        });
    });
});

function myFunction(username) {
   //.....
}
```

The pkg I used is one found on the npmjs website. `myFunction()` is always my function.

In my code you can see that i have implemented then/catch statement for when `myFunction()` fails.
So when that happens `error.ejs` is rendered.

But what happens when the npm package fails?
In the terminal i get the error message but there is no error handling on the server side.
This means, when it fails the user will not be notified with `error.ejs`, it is obvious since this functionality is omitted from my code.

But what are the ways to render `error.ejs`, when pkg fails?

Since I am already using `.then()/.catch()` technique below, can I also do it above?
In other words, can I nest `.then()/.catch()` statements?
Can I surround the outer code to a `try/catch` (while still having a `try/catch` inside)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pkg.impl_func()` appears to implement your typical Node.js callback interface (i.e. it returns an error as first argument in the event of an error or `null` if there's no error). You can simply check for the error's presence and render your `error.ejs` when it is present:

```
app.post('/aroute', function(req, res) {
  pkg.impl_func(data, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.render('error.ejs');
    } else {
      myFunction(entity).then(user=>{
        //DO_STUFF_HERE
        res.render('page.ejs');
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('error.ejs');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert `pkg.impl_func()` into an async function. Then you can use `promise.catch()` or `try-catch` inside an `async` function to simplify the syntax:

```
const util = require('util')
const impl_func_async = util.promisify(pkg.impl_func)

// traditional promises:
app.post('/aroute', (req, res) => {
  impl_func_async(data).then(result =>
    return myFunction(entity)
  }).then(user => {
    // DO_STUFF_HERE
    res.render('page.ejs')
  }).catch(e => {
    // Will catch thrown errors from impl_func_async and myFunction
    console.log(e)
    res.render('error.ejs')
  })
})

// async-await:
app.post('/aroute', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await impl_func_async(data)
    const user = await myFunction(entity)
    // DO_STUFF_HERE
    res.render('page.ejs')
  } catch (e) {
    // Will catch thrown errors from impl_func_async and myFunction
    console.log(e)
    res.render('error.ejs')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `try/catch` to wrap it all and render `error.js` in that catch also.

As for nesting `try/catch`...yes you can. In this case however a promise `catch()` is slightly different than a basic `try/catch`

```
app.post('/aroute', function(req, res) {

      try {
        pkg.impl_func(data, function(err, result) {
          myFunction(entity).then(user => {
            //DO_STUFF_HERE
            res.render('page.ejs');
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.render('error.ejs');
          });
        });

      } catch (e) {
        res.render('error.ejs');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i tried this and it didn't work. The error was thrown - as evident in the terminal, but there was no redirect to 'error.ejs'. (BTW, in your code you have one more pair of '});' that it is required.)